# t-SNE Choosing the Number of Dimensions

Tags: pca, data-analysis, dimensionality-reduction, multi-dimensional-scaling

I am using t-SNE for exploratory data analysis.  I am using this instead of PCA because PCA is linear and t-SNE is non-linear.

It's really straight-forward to know how many dimensions are required to capture the necessary variance with PCA.
How do I know how many dimensions are required for my data using t-SNE?

I have read a popular website of very useful information, but it doesn't discuss dimensionality.
https://distill.pub/2016/misread-tsne/

Comment: Asked 4 years ago, and still no answer!

Comment: @renakre Off-topic question simply are not answered, this is not the place for this question.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to start with 2 and experiment using higher values. Then analyse the visualisation and performance to know which gives a better clarity of results. This is the approach  I used when using t-sne for my project